# Debugging question closed as off-topic?

Tags: support

Asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979349/shared-memory-segment-getting-deleted?) on so earlier today.

I'm fine with this being marked as off-topic if that's what the moderators deem appropriate, but the justification is rather surprising:

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." – Olaf, Toby Speight, coder, Peter Haddad, slavoo

I mean, desired behavior is pretty clear, specific problem is clearly stated and can be reproduced, code is available through a link, and others will likely run into same issue in the future. What else do you need ?

Comment: Note that in your particular case, you were correct that your exact code wasn't important. That should have been a clue that you didn't actually have a programming question, but a configuration-of-Linux-system-services question. If you followed the advice in the below answers, your question would have stayed open... and you probably would not have gotten an answer. If instead you had asked about your system configuration at any of (SuperUser, AskUbuntu, Unix&Linux) you might have gotten a correct answer and no requests for code. Details of how the shm was named and who owned would be natural.

Comment: Admittedly you really had two questions related to your problem.  One, "For this code, am I doing something that will cause the shm file to be deleted?" (Because delete-on-close flags do exists), and two, "Would any of these processes running on my Ubuntu system possibly be deleting my shm special files?"  Each one would be appropriate on a different site and need different accompanying details.

Answer (score 26):

I want to call special attention to this remark:

> ...code is available through a link...

You left your code on an external site [linked through the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979349/shared-memory-segment-getting-deleted?#comment86975767_49979349).  If that comment link is deleted (and don't think it won't; comments are deleted for *any* reason), or if the Pastebin site itself goes dark (and don't think it won't), we no longer have your code.

**Always paste your code in the question.**  Without doing that your questions will always be susceptible to being closed for this reason.

Comment: Half surprised you didn't hightlight _"and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."_ in your answer, as it is spelled out right there in the close reason that the code has to be in the question itself.

Comment: In addition, a lot of big corporations have firewalls that block access to pastebin, among others.

Comment: @Kendra: The OP didn't notice it the first time, so phrasing it in a different way may be preferable...? (Honestly I was on autopilot for this answer...)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Didn't get the message until now. Aside from this, why all the hostility ? This site is becoming more and more user unfriendly ...

Comment: @lemonsqueeze Clarify what you mean by "hostility"? Because I don't see any. I see a question on the main site that didn't fit the rules downvoted and closed, and I see a question here that people disagree with (voting is different on Meta, some people just vote for disagreement/agreement) downvoted.

Comment: @lemonsqueeze I agree that the site is becoming more and more user unfriendly.  More and more users seem think that SO is a free, personal debugging service and that their questions don't need to be useful to future visitors/users.  Linking to the code off-site is hostile to those users who may find the link dead or unreachable.

Answer (score 9):

> and can be reproduced

By you, sure.

Not by anyone else, since your question doesn't contain enough information for anyone else to reproduce the problem, hence the closure.

Comment: Any developer with basic understanding of shared memory concepts can replicate the issue in less than half an hour.

Comment: @lemonsqueeze But then they would have no idea if what they did to cause the issue is what *you* did to cause the issue.  They need to be able to do precisely what you're doing, and verify that exactly the same problems arise, in order to accurately explain why you are getting the problem that you're getting.

Comment: @Lemonsqueeze Additionally, it is completely unreasonable to expect someone who is volunteering their time on Stack Overflow to help you to spend half an hour to replicate an issue when you are fully capable of providing the issue in its entirety for people to work from in less than 5 minutes. Why should someone help you if you can't be bothered to do your part in presenting the problem?

Comment: @DavyM sure, plus after serveral users have spent their 30 minutes duplicating the test code in parallel, the user posts 'Never mind - I had an environment path set wrong'.

Comment: @lemonsqueeze so... You have the repro steps but it's not important to give them explicitely because it would take someone half an hour to reproduce.... Considering you are asking for volunteers work, you could be more considerate about that.....

Comment: @lemonsqueeze: my usual comment to folks who don't post an MCVE is: You will want to create and post a valid [mcve] program with your question so that we can reproduce the problems ourselves with minimal difficulty and effort on our part (it is your question and so the effort should be yours).

Comment: @lemonsqueeze Are you seriously asking us to spend half an hour so that you don't have to spend time on writing a proper question when you're asking us for free help?