# How to handle a self-answer, which is a rant actually just refusing to provide the solution?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I just stumbled upon a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50370675/4235784) (now deleted, 10k only) which does not provide any substantial information and seems to be driven by frustation and the user getting in a huff:

> So I have found a solution to this problem which completely satisfies the criteria 1) and 2) above. Since no one can be bothered to help a beginner by offering helpful suggestions, I will not post the solution.

Clearly, this is not an answer and does not try to solve the problem, which makes it eligible for an NAA flag and deserves a downvote. However, I am not sure, if this is *enough*. I consider this post disrespectful towards the rest of the community and it shows a bad attitude, which does not play well with our [*be-nice policy*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

How should this behavior be dealt with? Is this worth bothering a moderator or should I just

1. downvote,
2. comment,
3. flag as NAA?

Comment: The question reveals the user's age.  It will get better when he gets older, no big deal.

Comment: @HansPassant: (I'm pretty sure) I was never this obnoxious when I was little...

Comment: @HansPassant You can't be sure about that. It may very well be their teacher.

Comment: No idea why I *have* to be sure, it is just as plausible an explanation as any.  Try to keep that glass half-full, tolerating each other's occasional missteps is by far the best way to keep everybody getting along with each other.

Comment: @HansPassant While it's likely you are correct, being middle-age myself I know a lot of middle-age and old `<Not worthy of typing her>` that posting an answer like that is right up their ally. my main point - you don't need to be young to act like a `<Again, I don't think I should use that language here>`.

Comment: Honestly the poster's response is appropriate. SO isn't nice to beginners at all. There's really no reason for beginners to be nice to SO. Doesn't matter though cause SO is incapable of admitting it. Even when the someone did finally admit it in the official blog, the community just held discussions which all avoided the actually problem at hand. Just admit that SO is not currently a website for beginners and move on.

Comment: @Steve: We can be nice to non-programmers (which is what most of the people you euphemistically call "beginners" really are) without making room for them on the site.  Telling them politely they're in the wrong place so they don't waste their time and breath is one of the nicest things one can do for them.  OTOH, being unwelcoming to off-topic unresearched posts does not in the slightest excuse claiming that kind of response is an answer, so the first sentence of your comment is 100% wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for providing an example of the problem Ben. It's not that the poster's response is an answer, it's that the poster is completely justified in being pissed at SO and has absolutely no reason to even try to follow the sites guidelines at this point.

Comment: @Steve: If by "problem" you mean "cool detached and unemotional response", then sure.  No, the poster is not justified in his attitude.  True that someone who doesn't meet the criteria for becoming a user has little reason to even try to follow the rules.  The site will survive.

Comment: @BenVoigt By problem I mean inability to confront mistakes, bias, and general wrong doing.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Addressing you as one of the three delete-voters of the **question**, not the answer: I think this is not a reasonable action. Sure, the answer was really bad, and IMO even deserved the meta effect. However, the question on its own wasn't that bad, in fact, it made me wonder why anyone would write a bad answer to their own good question. The question, for sure, wasn't worth 12 downvotes and deletion. It may have been worded cumbersomely, not easily accessible but it was just a variation of "how to filter select box based on other select box". It even contained the relevant parts...

Comment: ...of OP's code. I just voted to undelete, encouraging others to reconsider their actions. I'd rather see it closed as a duplicate of [*"How to filter select box based on value in preceding select box?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151792/how-to-filter-select-box-based-on-value-in-preceding-select-box). I totally agree with @HansPassant, that we should be "tolerating each other's occasional missteps", with the answer being one such misstep, the question being none.

Comment: @Steve: Where's the mistake or wrong doing, with respect to this user?  I see no unkind comments, or any engagement by the community.  Eventually a canned but clear message that a complete example is required but that came after the fake answer was posted.  The deletion came many hours after the original poster's impatient response.  Original poster doesn't even claim to have been mistreated, he claims to have been ignored.  That's life on a volunteer site -- there's no service level agreement promising help from a competent expert in a finite amount of time.  Unfortunate, but not wrongdoing.

Comment: @BenVoigt as per my first comment, "SO isn't nice to beginners at all. There's really no reason for beginners to be nice to SO. Doesn't matter though cause SO is incapable of admitting it. Even when the someone did finally admit it in the official blog, the community just held discussions which all avoided the actually problem at hand. Just admit that SO is not currently a website for beginners and move on". It's not just you. It's SO as a whole. It's also not really about this one user. It's about most beginners who use SO at the very beginning of their programming journey

Comment: @Steve: No one was anything other than nice.  The original poster complained about silence, not rudeness.  A very entitled attitude, that effectively express that he thinks someone is required to answer every question.  That's not "appropriate", that's treating experts like slaves.

Comment: @BenVoigt Here we go, as per my first comment, "SO isn't nice to beginners at all. There's really no reason for beginners to be nice to SO. Doesn't matter though cause SO is incapable of admitting it."

Comment: @Steve: Most beginners who use SO at the very beginning of their programming "journey" (or studies, or career) have a very fruitful experience.  It's the ones who equate "use SO" with "Hit the Ask a Question button" that frequently run into difficulty.  Reading, reading, and reading some more is the correct way to start "using" SO.

Comment: @BenVoigt APMFC, "Doesn't matter though cause SO is incapable of admitting it"

Comment: @Steve: You aren't paying any attention to what I'm saying.  You said "SO is not currently a website for beginners".  I adjusted that somewhat to "SO is not currently, and never was intended to be, a website for beginners to ask their questions".  Your first sentence was wrong.  The part of the answer you keep quoting, I agreed with, several times.  (Well, except that you're also wrong that SO is "incapable of admitting it".  The FAQ, I, and many other among the experts plainly say that it's a site for **professional and enthusiast programmers** only,)  Quit pretending that's a problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt APMFC " Even when the someone did finally admit it in the official blog", I'm guessing you haven't read that blog post.

Comment: @Steve: You show your ignorance with every comment.  If you researched SO's response to said blog post, as you claim, then surely you've seen [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366839/103167)

Comment: @Steve: Well, it's not a place for everyone.  It's a place for professional and enthusiast programmers.  [First sentence of the Welcome to Stack Overflow page.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)   Always has been.

Comment: @BenVoigt Pros and enthusiats includes beginners...

Comment: @BenVoigt , how does this sentence " We can be nice to non-programmers (which is what most of the people you euphemistically call "beginners" really are) without making room for them on the site. " show (or tell) that SO is "nice" to non programers? It sends the same message as : "this isn't my problem that i pushed you on the stairs and you broke your neck". If you don't make room for someone you are excluding it from society, that is opposite of human rights on right of opinion and free speech since you don't give them chance to talk. Also how can person become "enthusiast"?

Comment: And to add "unwelcoming to off-topic unresearched posts" please tell me where can user find that what is off topic. User finds an languages tag groups and how to ask a question but there is no readily available and readable information that shows limits of topics on stack overflow. Sure you can get some meta post from some years ago, but the truth is new user don't know how to find them - yet SO still allows them to ask questions. So you have SO bringing users without any information, throwing them to the lions and then complain " why people think we are unwelcoming?".

Comment: ": Where's the mistake or wrong doing, with respect to this user? I see no unkind comments, or any engagement by the community. " I can't see question in-question but i can tell you where is wrongdoing : based on in vitro looking at questions doing triages and other mod tools. If you have question "Why is A a not b?" and you have a bunch of answers complaining about missing comma and assignment... that is wrong doing you searched. Sure readability should and must be main focus, but under bunch of edits no one actually asked follow up question, just bunch of answers about commas and assignments

Comment: And to be honest, i did read your answer. I've found it intelligent and well spoken. I just am very curious what pushes people to go for self-defence instead of collective safety? What happened here so that all of you *expert users* became shut down and cold? And world has progressed a lot since game theory and economic principles. Countries give subventions to reward positive behaviour (such as charity and altruism ) in order to combat economics and game theory - while SO has none.

Comment: @Danilo: "how can person become *enthusiast*?"  By reading information already available and learning from good code by reading it and the accompanying explanation.  The rest of your comment about "same as i pushed you on the stairs" is just idiotic.  No one's problem is caused by Stack Overflow.  They're just upset because the problem they brought to Stack Overflow, they still have when they're shown the door (because they broke the rules).  But the problem already existed.

Comment: @Danilo: "world has progressed a lot since game theory and economic principles"  Complete and utter nonsense.  Game theory is a framework for understanding ALL economic incentives.  And the "rewards" you mention are not "given by countries", I can't think of a more absurd description of charity.

Comment: @BenVoigt No need for brass language, honestly. You may disagree with me, as I do with you in some points, but there is no need to escalate things or create offensive behaviour. But I am eager to read responses on other points made in comments when you chose to reply.

Comment: @Danilo: You're the one accusing people of (behavior that you consider to be the same as) pushing people down stairs and breaking necks, then refusing to render aid.  I find that offensive.  Users are not being "thrown to the lions" either, the site pleads with them to read the ["What can I ask about?" help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting their first question, which is exactly the "readily available and readable information that shows limits of topics on stack overflow" that you claim doesn't exist.  No one has to go sorting through old meta posts for that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Downvote,
2. Flag as "NAA",
3. Delete-vote,
4. Comment,
5. All of the above.

"Answers" like that do not answer the question, add no value to the site, and should be removed. All of the above actions help in that regard.
<sub>(Maybe aside from comments, which may only result in a "heated debate", in this case)</sub>

Here's the (now deleted) answer:
[image]

Comment: You are right: it's the heated debate I would like to avoid. On the other hand, I am not sure if the user gets the message if the post is just deleted in the end. That's why I asked about involving a moderator to make a clear statement that this behavior is not acceptable.

Comment: The post is now deleted (Last vote coming from a moderator)

Comment: With a nice comment, though, which managed to sneak in moments before deletion! No debate in this case...

Comment: Thx for qualifying my comment of nice. I tried to make it as neutral as possible @altocumulus

Comment: @cpburnz: This answer _explicitly_ avoided answering the question. It said as much in the answer. I can guarantee you that's a valid "NAA" flag.

Comment: It's okay. I figured it'd be best to add a screenshot, for context.

Comment: I would say comment on the question and not the answer, since the minute the answer gets deleted (and that took an hour at most) the only people that can read the comments to it are 10K+ users. If you comment on the question you might get a better chance the OP will see the comment.

Comment: you may add that the question doesn't add any value as well in the first place.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I believe users can always see their deleted content and the comments on them, so it shouldn't matter here, no? The only thing it takes away is the chance for that user to reply to me.... which is not necessarily a bad thing

Comment: @Patrice they can see their recently deleted posts, but they have to either do that from their questions/answers page, or to go directly to the question page.

Comment: There's no need to leave a comment under an inflamed post like that. It will usually end in more conflict. My advice would be use flags and votes.

Answer (score 23):

Flag as NAA, and downvote. I would not comment in this case. The self-answer is borderline trolling, and there's no point in feeding trolls.
I can see the temptation to give verbal negative feedback to an OP like this, but we're better than that.

Comment: can't we beg for the solution, though?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I suppose one could. I'd ignore the answerer's negativity. Something like, "hey, I have that problem too, can you tell me how you solved it?" The key, IMO, is to not respond to the negativity itself.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Considering the "answer" explicitly states not wanting to give an answer on SO. There's not much we can get out of that.

Comment: I wouldn't call a deeply _frustrated_ user a "troll". There's a significant difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Consider taking the high road and encouraging people to contribute to the community, while also setting the appropriate expectations.

There's at least some chance the user is just trying to feel heard - and lashing out doesn't fix that problem. Even if the user doesn't change their ways, this approach still builds a welcoming environment.

Answer (score 0):

The post is presumably bad content, so downvote, deletevote and flag as not an answer.

But is it evil enough to be flagged as "Rude and Abusive", which can result in serious consequences? Unless it's targeting a specific user, or a protected group of people (eg gender), I'd say no.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Does someone think the answer *should* be flagged as rude/abusive?

Comment: @BoltClock Obviously not, but this answer slightly misses the point as neither my question nor any other answer nor any comment even mentioned the "rude and abusive" flag. It's an answer to a question that was not asked (OT on my own behalf: is there an english word for this?)  Had this been a comment, fair enough, but as an answer, I don't know. Disclaimer: I was one of the downvoters.

Comment: Your question talked about the post violating the “be nice” policy, and talked about doing “something more”. The only “something more”s I know of, or ways of enforcing “be nice”, are either a custom flag, which is for a situation so odd no normal categories apply, or flagging as rude and abusive.