# Force deletion to provide an explanation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers

I recently came across a rant on Twitter from an important answerer on (link removed since people focus on the answer instead of the reaction)

TL;DR, one of his answers was deleted by a moderator, without any explanation whatsoever.
This made him frustrated to the point where he wants to leave the website.

**The deletion being right or wrong doesn't really matter here, it's more about the frustration created.**

Would it be feasible to **force** all delete flags (including from moderators) to include an explanation on *why* this question/answer should be removed?

This would reduce the frustration caused by such situation where it's not immediately obvious why the answer was deleted, and one of his tweets made a fair point:

> There is no drawback to the answer remaining. There are obvious drawbacks to deleting info that would be useful to the user.

Comment: Why add fuel to the fire by engaging with a Tweeter?  SO mods and/or curators do not, in general, behave in a masochistic, suicidal fashion by street-fighting with social media.

Comment: @MartinJames I have [just engaged with him](https://twitter.com/XplodingCabbage/status/1201248511519576065), because I think he has a fair complaint and people with fair complaints deserve to be engaged with even if they aren't gracious about how they voice them. I'd rather we fix our mistake (if indeed it was one, which it seems to me it was) and thus take a small step towards earning this man's goodwill, than write off him and his legitimate grumble because he made it a tad belligerently on Twitter.

Comment: @MartinJames His wording doesn't really matter. It's about what can _StackOverflow_ do to improve, not about what _he_ can do. It is a known fact that SO feels unwelcoming, and this is an example of such a situation felt by a big user. It should be our goal to reduce such friction as much as possible.

Comment: Link-only answers are unwelcome.

Comment: @MartinJames that's not the point. I wrote it in bold that whether the deletion was right or wrong doesn't matter. It's about _how_ it was done.

Comment: ..as are suggestions that voters/closers/deleters wast....flus....spend volunteer time on, likely pointless, explanations that paint the curators as targets:(

Comment: An explanation ***is*** provided underneath deleted answers by the system. This is fully automatic. It is not necessary for moderators to leave comments, unless they have something more specific to say that isn’t covered in the general [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @CodyGray An automatic link feels pretty inhumane and doesn't tell which of the specific clause the answer fell for. Also, the perception varies between people. For example, in the quoted case, the author disagrees that his answer is "link-only".

Comment: The entire point of this suggestion is to fight against the feeling of SO being "unwelcoming". There are clear stats showcasing that this is an issue with SO, and this case is just one example

Comment: Any solution is going to feel inhumane. I’m a strong advocate of having the system do this for us as a matter of convenience and tone, but even if moderators manually leave a comment, it’s going to be the same copy-pasted boilerplate, likely generated by a userscript. Nothing else is feasible. You have to understand the scale of moderation on SO. When I process flags, I’ll delete *hundreds* of non-answers. Even if, as you say below, leaving a comment only takes 5 seconds, that adds up to far more time than I’m willing to spend on low-quality answers I’ve already determined need deletion.

Comment: And none of that is going to fix the root problem that you identified: interpretations vary on how to apply the standards. This user disagreed that their answer was “link-only”. I am...not sure how. I’m on record as disliking “link-only” as a standard because it is poorly descriptive and often misleading, but this case is pretty clear. When you remove the link, the answer contains no useful information. That’s a problem, as links regularly degrade. These details fit better into a long-form Help Center article than a comment, which has a character limit.

Comment: @CodyGray it could be as simple as a modal similar to the close flag, which would list all the different possibilities for deletion. Anything that adds meaningful information other than "maybe its one of _these_" will help. And preserving the time of moderators in favor of not frustrating the community is a weird trade-off. We could just have each individual moderator do less but of a better quality, and have more moderators.

Comment: In any case, it's not by doing nothing that anything will change. There is a problem, that is the community feels unwelcomed, and it needs to be solved. It cause many people to give up on participating, which hurts the community on the long run.

Comment: A far larger problem that is hurting the community and discouraging participation is low-quality posts. Spending more time on dispatching low-quality posts is just going to make the problem worse. I have no particular interest in making the site more “welcoming” for contributors of low-quality content. We don’t want to optimize for that. Yes, you could have a buffet of choices, but they all fall into the category of “low quality post that does not meet our standards for an answer”, which is what the Help Center article explains. Most deleted answers have a variety of problems, not just one.

Comment: @CodyGray Everybody wrote at least some low quality posts. That's part of the learning curve. But if we're hateful toward that person and don't help him improve, then they just give up before being important members of the community. And no, the help center is definitely not good enough.

Comment: If low quality posts fits more than one thing, they make the modal use checkboxes instead of radio. But it's important to have at least one article per issue. With that bullet list, it doesn't mention what's the problem with link-only answers and why copy-pasting the content from the link is good. People can't guess that.

Comment: @RémiRousselet "_But if we're hateful toward that person_" - Deleting posts and providing an automated link is not exactly "hateful", is it?

Comment: @RémiRousselet The problem of scaling is serious when we would try to help by individual messages. And it is exhausting. Yesterday I saw a new user being hostile to an established user for politely being told that code only answers could be improved. I pondered chiming in with links, but didn't in the end: a user leaving a comment like that _will_ argue. It is _very_ rare that I see users improving their posts, even after being shown what to do or why it is downvoted. It's a frustrating waste of time in most cases - unfortunately.

Comment: Copy-pasting the information from the link is *never* good. Then it becomes plagiarism or reuse without permission. You need to *summarize* the information from the linked resource. I’m 99% sure this is covered in the Help Center. If it’s not, then we definitely need to improve that Help Center article. Please post a feature request for that. Regarding the assertion of “hatefulness”, I can’t really say it any better than Modus Tollens. I would also reiterate what I said earlier about how we don’t focus on people, but on content. Our job is not to coach people on how to improve their writing.

Comment: The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) inserted automatically does not clarify anything about link-only answers. It might be somewhere, but it's not an immediate explanation. You can't expect people to read all the articles when they are not even sure what the reason is. It should be broad clear what the issue is, and how to fix it. Like "deleted because link only", with a link to an article showing why they are deleted and what we can do instead.

Comment: @RémiRousselet So what do you propose, apart from tending to each user individualy? Any idea on how to make the experience better for both sides without a link?

Comment: @ModusTollens Voluntarily not trying to help is hateful. People feeling hurt because SO is harsh is a common thing. What is wrong with requiring one extra click from a moderator if that alleviates even just a bit the feeling of frustration? It's a community. We should try to help people when they feel rejected by the site.

Comment: @ModusTollens I proposed adding a modal with checkbox that would customize the delete link. Combined with a custom article for each potential reason. Currently the generic link doesn't help enough

Comment: *“This includes answers that are … barely more than a link to an external site …”* It is definitely called out there. Are you thinking there should be more explanation of *why* that is a problem? Perhaps we could link that to https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing? There’s also a good explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, which everyone should be required to read before posting any answers to this site (and...I think they maybe are, but I’m not certain; the flow has changed far too many times since I have tested with a new account).

Comment: The how to answer isn't very helpful here IMO. It says what's good, but bad content is not very visible. Maybe a DO/DON'T format? Like "do include references when possible" vs "don't answer with just a link. Instead extract the important content of the link. That is to prevent a situation where a link dies, and the answer becomes useless. It's more readable because the bad thing becomes instantly visible

Comment: _"Voluntarily not trying to help is hateful"_. Accusing volunteers of acting _out of hate_, or saying that their actions are _deserving of hate_, because they do not raise to whatever bar you feel it's the minimum they should raise to, is very unkind at best. This kind of language only helps at sabotaging whatever case you may have.

Comment: @RémiRousselet "_Voluntarily not trying to help is hateful._" - Take a look at my profile at SO. 4251 helpful flags. Lots of those were accompanied by polite, user-tailored comments. Postive reactions? Extremely few. Insults? Many. No reaction? Most. Still I do it, but not always: I have to take care of my own wellbeing as well to be able to keep doing it. I deserve to have a positive experience on SO as well. If automated links help take a bit of the burden from moderating users, I'm all for it. We simply can not personally help every single user.

Comment: An additional, personal note: accusing moderating users of being hateful when not jumping up ready to help each user on demand is _really making me angry_. Not at you personally, at the situation. Want to make SO better? Chime in, flag, vote etc. Or complain constructively, no problem. But leave "hateful" at the door.

Comment: Volunteer work does not justify hurting people. I understand that there's a big load, but it shouldn't be a factor in determining whether the work performed is of a good enough quality of not.

Comment: If the word "hateful" hurts some of you, then I apologize for it. I do think that everybody here tries to at least think of making things better. But I do think that the current situation _do_ need some improvements

Comment: It personally hurts me a lot when I try to recommend SO to people, and the most common answer I get is "I can't because it's a toxic community". That should not be the opinion of the public.

Comment: It isn't the opinion of the public, it is the opinion of few people who (still) don't have a clue what Stack Overflow and how it works. Way to many people think they get free coders to do their homework or others think they can post a link and everyone will kiss their butt for that. They obviously will be disappointed.

Comment: It is possible to volunteer while doing a bad job at it. They are not incompatible. The stats say it quite clearly: the community thinks that SO is an unwelcoming place

Comment: For me, apologizing is not nearly enough. I find it abhorrent that you could say that hate is in any way involved in a situation like this. I think it is absolutely absent of empathy and introspection. That the platform could do a better work to set-up expectations? Good, something we could work on, to an extent. But the problem is not the action of the moderator (that they deleted the answer, or if they posted an additional personalized comment to "justify" their actions), but the expectations of the user posting the answer. That disconnect is what's causing the "problem", such as it is.

Comment: One last thing for the bigger picture you might have missed: reactions from new users to messages from other users trying to help. Warning: not safe for work. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/1288408

Comment: The "community" certainly does not think that. I'm not sure why you think yourself entitled to declare "who" the community is. There are individuals who think that, and that there other individuals peddling narratives of "hate" certainly does not help at all. Again, the problem is the disconnect between what the platform is supposed to be, and what some users expect of it.

Comment: Let's ditch this _"welcoming"_ discussion. It's been had again and again and is barely related to this question anyway

Comment: @yivi What other word would you use to describe a situation where it is acknowledged by surveys that users feel unwelcomed, but volunteers refuse to adapt? As a non native English speaker, I do not know any other word. It's part of SO policies to "do it right or don't do it". Nobody force volunteers to do something that cause users to feel threatened

Comment: I'm a not a native English speaker either. But words as "hate" or "threat" have very clear, direct, easy translations to French, so that excuse wears **very** thin. If despite that you insist that that language is the appropriate one, you are part of the problem, making this place a less safe for everyone by projecting a narrative that certainly does not fit the reality.

Comment: Surveys says that **some** users feel "unwelcomed". Surveys also say that **most** users find SO an **extremely useful resource**. (Even without surveys, we know this for a fact). As I say again and again, the problem is one of expectations: the site works and it is useful **because** of its rules. Some users do not realize that those rules are in place, so they have a mismatch between expectations and reality. We should do a better work at communicating what to expect, so users do not get surprised by how it works. Experienced users should help.

Comment: It's not me but the surveys that says users feels unwelcomed. A few comments above, someone mentioned how flags may cause insults. Voluntarily continuing without changing something that is known to cause insults is harsh.

Comment: Care to point to what surveys you keep referring?

Comment: I agree that we should do a better job at communicating these rules. That's the whole point of this meta post to begin with.

Comment: No, the whole point of your question is that we should "force moderators to explain why they delete posts". It's black and white up there in the question.  A secondary point made in the question is that maybe the post shouldn't have been deleted at all. It's there in the quote you provide. And appropriately communicating the rules is not up to the moderators, but up the site owners.

Comment: Forcing an explanation instead of just a generic link is part of the "improving the communication on what those rules are". It should be as clear as possible for people to understand what they failed and what they should do next.

Comment: I'm afraid that this suggestion is, essentially, just another attempt to get SO curators to waste volunteered time on, likely, counter-productive twitterable exchanges.  If users want extended explanations, they should expect to pay for them.  Why is it ALWAYS curators/mods fault for any perceived problems?  Why are there continual suggestions that 'someone else' has to put in extra effort to help new accounts?  How can it be believed that so many 'elitist, bigoted, misogynist, fascist, hostile, unwelcoming' etc people have all arrived as curators/mods?

Comment: I'm not saying it's the fault of volunteers (unless they don't want to change). But only _us_ can do something. We have a communication issue, and only those that have the knowledge of the site can do something about it. My suggestion was merely a suggestion, not a blame.

Comment: @RémiRousselet So what do _you_ do about it? Do you guide new users? I feel like many volunteers do more than enough already. It's unpaid life time.

Comment: It even was acknowledged publicly by SO that there's a problem, and that it is not _our_ fault but _their perception_ that is flawed. But should we ignore it? I personally don't want to participate in the flag queues because I know that I may hurt some people (as I'm bad at wording like you could have guessed from this thread).

Comment: @ModusTollens when I see one of such case face to face, I carefully explain to them that it is not us being hateful, just strict rules. It takes a few hours of discussion though.

Comment: @RémiRousselet A few hours for one user? And how many users need guidance a day? I spent over an hour over the last 2 days trying to help a new user. They still throw a fit because they are not interested in SO. They just want their question answered. Unfortunately it took all this time to figure that out. Many more (willing) users could have been helped in that time.

Comment: It's obviously not scalable indeed. I'm not saying it's the solution, I just answered your question. I prefer to take it slow and make sure I don't hurt anybody.

Comment: In any case, this thread is going on the wrong direction. It was merely a suggestion to offend less people. It is pretty clear that people dislike the idea (although I don't get why a simple modal is too much). So we can probably stop there.

Comment: @RémiRousselet sure, SO has acknowledged that there is a problem.  They are not making enough money, and that must be someone's fault.  Who is to blame?  They have all these mails and Tattler/Facepalm posts from misguided/entitled/deadbeat users who got their questions downvoted/closed/deleted, so it must be the curators at fault.  The curators were duly run over by the welcome wagon in an attempt to 'reeducate' them to serve as lookup slaves and homework drones.  I am not willing to change if that involves wasting time on users who will shoot me on Twitter at any perceived slight.  WONTFIX

Comment: I see from your account, @Rémi, that you have very little reviews, almost no flags, and some votes.  That's a fairly small amount of curation work, compared to the people you're arguing with.  It's hard to really have a conversation with someone who hasn't had the same experience, put in the time, if you will.  You're advocating that those who are most invested in the site should invest *even more* of themselves into it, to help those not even willing to invest enough to educate themselves, let alone help the site.  That's a pretty unbalanced expectation.

Comment: Fallacy of personal attack, nice. Avoid it next time, especially in a discussion about being "unwelcoming". And clearly, with 800+ answers on this site, I do invest enough time on it to at least be able to speak about it.

Comment: You can speak to contributing answers.  You can't speak to actually *curating* the site.  Your argument is that others, those that *do* try to keep the site clean, should spend more time so that others get more help that they didn't try to learn themselves.  That argument would have *way* more weight if it came from a place of personal experience.  I feel there should be a balance between curators and new users; we need to be as welcoming as we can, but in turn, new users need to be able to acclimate themselves to the site without requiring hand holding.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Did you see my "user reaction" link earlier? Those are personal attacks moderating users encounter frequently. And they still have to keep cool and professional. Those reactions are what you would see as well. That is the experience you are missing: volunteers being verbally abused. And those users are now - again - being called "hateful". Try to see _both_ sides, please, and avoid "hateful" accusations. That's all I'm asking.

Comment: @fbueckert that's another fallacy. Everybody is entitled to voice their opinion, even newcomers (they are directly concerned anyway). Also, I said previously that I purposefully do not use these features because they create hate. I prefer to leave a simple comment. For example, I have the rights to auto-close as dups Flutter question, but purposefully will leave a "consider reading <link>" comment instead, to avoid hate.

Comment: @ModusTollens I do not reject that both sides have their issues. I'm not defending them. I agree that both sides should do their best to stop insults and rejections.

Comment: Until you can see curation *as* curation, I don't think there's any point in trying to convince you.  Stating that it's hate only hardens opposition to your viewpoint.  So...meh.  You're not interested in even trying to curate, so I see no reason to continue discussing this with you.

Comment: You're deforming my words. I never said that people reviewing flags are haters, but that using flags may cause hate (even undesired). You're rejecting my point of view just because I disagree with yours, that's sad.

Answer (score 24):

I can't explain how much I hate Twitter Driven Meta Moderation but I fixed it for you and the OP.

I gave that answer an edit and flagged it for a moderator to be undeleted. Something both you and the OP could have done.

Moderators respond to thousands of flags per day. They don't have the time, nor is it needed, to pamper each action with welcoming comments. We operate under the assumption that when you're 13 years or older that you have enough capabilities to figure out why something got down, close or delete voted. And if you can't there is a great meta site with even more valuable resources and even users that are happy to point anyone into the right direction.

If you mod flag a post for undeletion (that is the only option you have for mod-deleted posts and that is by design) make sure you address the issue that is present in the post. So you can at least say in your flag text that you tried to fix the post among your argument why undeletion is warranted.

Despite popular belief these sites (both main and meta) work because of the invested community of elected moderators and users with trusted privileges. Meta is the shortest route to discuss mishaps that happened.

If you think there is too much deleted, do use the [Tools/Deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=today) if you're above 10K. It does show recent deleted and even recent delete voted posts. You can then act before the case gets to Twitter. For example, leave a comment explaining why a post is about to be deleted. Or fix it. Or both.

> There is no drawback to the answer remaining. There are obvious drawbacks to deleting info that would be useful to the user.

Yes, there is a drawback. It would indicate to others that just dropping a link in an answer is fine here. It is not, for at least the last 6 to 8 years. Also when links go 404 all the "info useful to the user" has been gone. On top of that I can't stress enough that we shouldn't optimize for the OP. We should optimize content for visitors to come. And when they reach an SO Q/A they expect to find the answer here. Not yet another redirection to an off-site resource. If they prefer that experience they should have stayed at the Google search result page.

The drawback for leaving subpar posts is that SO become like Yahoo! Answers. They don't need another "competitor" in the low quality crap segment. I give you it is easy to get there, as there are no rules to follow.

You're all welcome.

Comment: That's off-topic, and I already flagged it for undeletion (and he himself said he can't). 
It's not about what's right or wrong here. I'm saying "why is it allowed to delete an answer without giving an explanation?".

Comment: Also, since it comes from a moderator, the casual "undelete" button doesn't work, and we can only "flag for moderator intervention".

Comment: The answerer most certainly *can* flag their own answers for moderator attention, including to request undeletion. So, while it’s true that moderator-deleted answers can’t simply be undeleted by the community (which is necessary to prevent folks unfamiliar with our quality standards from creating more work for moderators), there is definitely an escape hatch. And yeah, as mentioned above, an explanation *is* provided for deleted answers.

Comment: @RémiRousselet you flagged but didn't fix it? Why? You did took plenty of time to Tweet and write a meta post about it. That seems strange.

Comment: The post you've quoted in your edit can't be the one the post was originally referring to, based on the date. We've now got an answer dated October 20th saying that a dev said something 11 days ago, and seemingly purporting to quote that thing... but actually quoting something from September.

Answer (score 18):

I feel like [rene's answer and actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391789/1079354) underscore what the *actual* problem is.

**The answer was *poor* because it was link-only.**  Link-only answers are subject to deletion, without mercy or explanation.

We missed a key opportunity to educate the OP on adding more detail to their answer, especially if it's cited from a link.  If that link disappears one day, then the answer is worthless in the context of Stack Overflow.

But, at the end of the day, it's now fixed.  The answer is *better* than it was before it was edited, and the value persists even if the link disappears.  One Twitter fire extinguished.  Y'all can pat yourselves on the back now.

Comment: I do agree with the reasoning, that's what [I said to him](https://twitter.com/remi_rousselet/status/1201218900874149890). But that's not the point. The point is, why is the "without mercy or explanation" allowed?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I thought that Remy 'links go stale' explanation here was pretty clear.  The problem with link-only answers is also clearly explained in the SO rules/policy/tour - the info that the OP should know.

Comment: I litteraly said it to him myself that his answer was link-only. That's not the point. Why couldn't the moderator just add a "deleted because it is a link-only answer. See <link>". That takes 5 seconds and would remove/reduce the frustration of not understanding what happened.

Comment: Yeah... Just looking at that Twitter thread gives me a sneaking suspicion that this wouldn't have reduced the frustration. Frustration is seldom expressed as, "I don't know why I waste time on that site". A golden opportunity was missed to have the OP come to Meta and get this explanation.

Comment: That assumes they were looking for an explanation, @Makoto. People who turn to Twitter inevitably aren’t, and especially people who say things like, “I don’t know why I waste time on that site.” Sounds more like a bullet was dodged by not having yet another unconstructive rant on Meta.

Comment: @RémiRousselet moderators handle thousands of flags each day, they don't have the time to pamper each case in welcomeness. We assume we deal here with grown-ups that have some capabilities to figure out what a down, close or delete vote means. If you think you can do better then please nominate in the next mod election.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. While @rene's edit did indeed improve the deleted answer, I don't think it was "link-only" or deserving of deletion before the edit. Even in its [previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58475753/1) it told us, without us following the link, that the behaviour is a bug, it's reported on the Flutter bug tracker & soon going to be fixed in Flutter, & that it affects physical devices (implicitly: not simulators). That's enough information to deserve to exist. It's good that rene's quote now adds some extra detail and substantiation, but also supererogatory.

Comment: “Link-only answers are subject to deletion, without mercy or explanation.” Link-only answers should be change to comments, not deleted.
From [shog9 post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)
“if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer “